# Error in Google Colab WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome("/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver")

WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/chromium-browser is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

P.S - Both selenium and chrome drivers are up to-date.I can't understand Why is this error occurring.

Comment: Are you using the correct chrome driver version?

Comment: I am using google colab and the chrome driver version is latest version.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google-Colab-Selenium

```
!pip install google-colab-selenium
```

Then you can use Selenium as such:

```
import google_colab_selenium as gs


driver = gs.Chrome()

driver.get('https://www.google.com')
print(driver.title)
driver.quit()
```